# Password policy in Redis

Tags: redis

I have Redis Community Ver 6.2.5 . I have setup TLS/SSL cluster nodes (3 master/3 slave).
All configuration and integration are ok.
However we need to setup password policy for accounts in Redis. The password policies is similar to LDAP or SQL password policies.
Can Redis have tools to setup password policy ? Redis default password and security are not sufficient to protect our critical setup.
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at Redis ACL.

Comment: I am looking for password policy similar SQL Database for example password change every quarterly and min password length/character allowed and etc

Comment: Anyone have any ideas ?  We have strict security policies hence Redis ACL default security did not meet our specification.